# Java modules calling Spring context throws BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

All though I see lots of questions, some answers are not relevant to my setup.
I have a total of 3 modules API, Impl and consumer. Consumer has dependency of API and Impl. Consumer has web.xml, which looks like

```
<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath*:/**/conf/spring-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.name.TestMe</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</webapp>
```

In consumer resource conf/spring-config.xml exists with configuration

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd">

<import resource="classpath*:/**/repository.xml"/>
</beans>
```

within repository.xml I have

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:/**/properties/mongo-config.properties
                </value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- <import resource="config/mongo-core.xml" /> -->
    <import resource="config/spring-core.xml" />

</beans>
```

Am I missing anything here?

The whole stacktrace is as below

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:170)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at com.name.TestMe.doGet(TestMe.java:31)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
```

Comment: where are you declaring your beans? are you using @repository annotation?

Comment: Please show the whole stacktrace.

Comment: Thats correct in the Impl i am using @Repository annotation.

Comment: Could you show what is line 31 in `TestMe.java` ?

Comment: ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext();
mongoRepository = (MongoRepository)context.getBean("mongoRepositoryImpl");
am trying to fetch the bean from application context. mongoRepositoryImpl is comming from the Impl module

Comment: anymore ideas or thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Oups, you should never write something like

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext();
mongoRepository = (MongoRepository)context.getBean("mongoRepositoryImpl");
```

as you showed in you last comment ! You create a new empty and uninitialized application context, instead of using the one created by spring `ContextLoaderListener`.

Spring allows you to wire beans, either automatically or explicitely, but your own classes should not directly access the application context except for very special use cases. It should be enough to write (just a guess because I do not know your config, but it is an example) :

```
@Autowired
MongoRepository mongoRepository;
```

If you configuration contains exactly one bean of type `MongoRepository`, and if `TestMe` is also a spring bean, then spring will automatically *wire* them. If you have more than one bean of same type, you can specify the name with `@Qualifier` annotation :

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("mongoRepositoryImpl")
MongoRepository mongoRepository;
```

Of course, you can also define that in xml config.